# Is the power button on my iPhone being turned off programmatically?

Tags: sleep-wake, command-line, iphone

I would like to know if there is a code / glitch to make the sleep/wake button on the iPhone 5/5S to stop working. i am almost 100% certain it exists due to some programmers making the code but i want to know if anyone on here knows or heard about it.

Comment: Despite it being a likely hardware error, what reasons are making you suspect software?

Answer (score 2):

The likely cause is hardware failure, and not software.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost certainly a hardware failure. There is known hardware defect with some early iPhone 5 units that causes the sleep/wake button to stop working.

Apple has acknowledged the problem and is offering to repair devices that were manufactured with this defect. You can go to [Apple's support site](https://ssl.apple.com/support/iphone5-sleepwakebutton/) to see if your device qualifies for repair and, if it does, to get instructions for how to get your phone repaired.